# PHP login error "Undefined Variable"

Tags: php, android

Sir I am using a login.php script in my android application.Everything with the script is running fine if I am posting a valid username and password but when I am leaving both the fields blank or I am entering some incorrect information I am getting an error "Undefined variable login_ok". Kindly help me as I don't know much about php scripts.Thanks in advance

My login.php script is

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }

    //This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
    //we initialize it as false.
    $validated_info = false;

    //fetching all the rows from the query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
        //compare the two passwords
        if ($_POST['password'] === $row['password']) {
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
    if ($login_ok) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else {
?>
        <h1>Login</h1> 
        <form action="login.php" method="post"> 
            Username:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            Password:<br /> 
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" value="" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 
        </form> 
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have no rows, you are not setting the $login_ok variable, so, when you do

```
if ($login_ok) {
```

you are accessing a variable which is not defined.
use

```
if(isset($login_ok) && $login_ok)) {
```

instead of your if, or set $login_ok = false; when you have no rows.